# Very Big CSV File - How to Read Only Certain Rows into Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning, dask

I have a very large csv file that I cannot use pandas read_csv to load to my computer memory.

I look at `dask.dataframe as dd`

I need to use dask to read only certain rows of certain columns from that csv file and store it as a panda dataframe.

For example:

```
User  ProductA  ProductB
A     1         2
B     2         3
C     3         1
```

**How can I only read the row for user C and column ProductA using dask ?**

Required output as data frame:

```
User  ProductA
C     3
```

Comment: can you show the raw csv ?

Comment: @anon01 it has 32 million rows and 25 columns

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `read_csv` function of `dask.dataframe`, filter and then transform your `df` to a pandas dataframe:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

path2file = "yourpath.csv"
cols = ["User", "ProductA"]
# Be careful about the sep (check if it is ; or something else and add it to the
# function below as parameter if so
dataset = dd.read_csv(path2file, usecols=cols)
# Filter 
dataset = dataset.loc[dataset["User"]=="C"]), :]
dataset = dataset.compute()
```

Comment: Nice, this works too. my initial hack was to simply read the big file into chunks of smaller csv file with pandas, and then work with these smaller chunks to extract the users

Comment: The code is broken, unable to edit do to queue being full. Delete the last 5 characters in the second last line to fix the code:
`dataset = dataset.loc[dataset["User"]=="C"]`